# Checking if port is open in certain ip in java/js/jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I'm trying to make java program that checks ip addresses and it's ports and return whether it is listening or not. Since it is web based programing that I'm doing, I want the program to be really light and efficient. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just FYI, the class of program you want to make here is called a [*port scanner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [`Socket`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/net/Socket.html) API from Java for this. If no one is listening at an IP:PORT, you get a "Connection refused" exception thrown. How you want to continue further check if the connection gets accepted is something you would/should know about.